# How to clone Swift generic array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I need to deep copy a `Swift` generic array. I can do it one by one in a for loop, but there might be a more compact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var myArray = [Double](count: 5, repeatedValue: 1.0)
NSLog("%@", myArray)
var copiedArray = myArray
NSLog("%@", copiedArray)
```

Comment: yes, meantime I noticed that assigning with `=` makes a true copy, not only the reference is set

Comment: This is actually a shallow copy. Work for `Double` as they are value types, but what about class types like `NSString`?

Comment: Just initialise your array as strings : 
var threeDoubles = [String](count: 3, repeatedValue: "myString")
for any other type initialise it with your type of object

Comment: copiedArray is a shallow copy of myArray in swift.

Comment: This is indeed a shallow copy

Answer (score 2):

For deep copying, for normal objects what can be done is to implement a protocol that supports copying, and make the object class implements this protocol like this:

```
protocol Copying {
    init(original: Self)
}

extension Copying {
    func copy() -> Self {
        return Self.init(original: self)
    }
}
```

And then the Array extension for cloning:

```
extension Array where Element: Copying {
    func clone() -> Array {
        var copiedArray = Array<Element>()
        for element in self {
            copiedArray.append(element.copy())
        }
        return copiedArray
    }
}
```

and that is pretty much it, to view code and a sample check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sohayb/4ba350f7e45c636cb3c9)

Answer (score 0):

@Sohayb Hassoun approved function to clone array:

```
extension Array where Element: Cloneable {

    func clone() -> Array {
        let copiedArray: Array<Element> = self.compactMap { $0.cloned() }
        return copiedArray
    }

}
```